# Not able to connect to backend over https from ionic android app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, content-security-policy

Unable to connect to backend over "https" on android app created through ionic CLI.

It works perfectly fine on browser, on debug mode on android phone. Just doesn't work in release mode. It even works over 'http' but not on 'https'.

And my SSL certificate is not self-signed. It is properly bought certificate and all SSL checkers say it is fine.

Tried all the solutions I could find on internet.

1. Installed whitelist-plugin.
2. Re-installed whitelist-plugin.
3. Added Content-security-policy with "*" for default-src.

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; script-src *;">`

4. Added   `<allow-intent href="*" />
          <allow-navigation href="*" />`

Looks like app itself blocking the request from going out.
Nothing seems working. Please help.

Comment: can you share what errors are you getting

Comment: How do I even debug and see the error on phone. I can not even inspect through chrome extension as it is in release mode and it is working fine in debug mode.

Comment: @PrateekJain Have you solved this issue, for me, my APIs are https and certificate based authenticated, where I am getting Error code 0 issue.

Comment: @Mrunal No I couldn't solve this. Just left it there because of time constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The very simple solutions is, allow two ports in your API like

3001 for SSL / HTTPS and 3002 for HTTP.. This way your app works and your site runs perfectly in HTTPS

My code is as follows which worked perfectly:

```html
var express = require('express');
var DataController = require('./user/DataController');
var UserController = require('./user/UserController');
var db = require('./database/database-db'); 
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
next();
});

app.use('/user', UserController);
app.use('/data', DataController);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send("Welcome to the secure mobile and web development world");
});

// This settings are for HTTPS, SSL web applications.

// var https = require("https");
// var fs = require("fs");

// var options = {
//   key: fs.readFileSync("/home/path/ssl/keys/key.key"),
//   cert: fs.readFileSync("/home/path/ssl/certs/crt.crt")
  
//   };

// https.createServer(options,app).listen(3001);
// console.log('Welcome to the security world')


// This settings are only for HTTP sites

// var http = require("http");
// var fs = require("fs");

// http.createServer(app).listen(3001);
// console.log('Welcome to the security')



//This settings are for both HTTPS,HTTP SSL web applications.

var https = require("https");
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("/home/path/ssl/keys/key.key"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("/home/path/ssl/keys/crt.crt")
  };

https.createServer(options,app).listen(3001);
console.log('Welcome to the security world')
http.createServer(app).listen(3002);
console.log('Welcome to the proxy world')
```